# PostGIS: ST_INTERSECTS (Points on Polygons) takes ages to calculate

Tags: postgresql, postgis

currently I am working on creating a table which has all Points from a table which intersect with polygons from a different table - they are just 2D Points on Water. I made this sql code based on my experience but it takes ages to complete and pgadmin4 is not completing it. The Data is fine, points are ok, polygons are okay, I tested it with a different script and got a table at the end with two geometry columns (one for each points and polygons) but that's not the final workflow I was looking for.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE vt_views.intersect_points
TABLESPACE pg_default
AS
 SELECT * FROM vt_views.points
WITH DATA;
 
ALTER TABLE vt_views.intersect_points
    OWNER TO postgres;
 
ALTER TABLE vt_views.intersect_points
    ADD Water VARCHAR(4);
 
UPDATE vt_views.intersect_points
SET Water = 'Yes' FROM vt_views.intersect_points, vt_views.polygons WHERE ST_Intersects (vt_views.intersect_points.geom, vt_views.polygons.geoloc);
 
GRANT ALL ON TABLE vt_views.intersect_points TO postgres;
 
CREATE INDEX intersect_points_geom_idx
    ON vt_views.intersect_points USING gist
    (geom)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Maybe you guys can help me here. In the end I am looking just for the point table which has a "Yes" in each cell where it intersects with a water polygon. If not there should be NULL

Comment: Can you add the explain analyze to your question? Also, make sure you have an index on your polygon geom.

Comment: All tables are indexed

Comment: Showing us `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT` doesn't really help when you don't show the underlying table it is selecting from.

Comment: intersect_points is specified twice in the UPDATE with the same alias.  This is not legal, and if it were it would probably be doing the wrong thing.